# Transactions with multiple origins?

Tags: transactions

See [this](https://blockchain.info/tx/968b0bd7288129dd918a95c81b46384af40a7ab35545e5e4dcfefe68e05a67a6) transaction.

How can a transaction have multiple origins? Surely one transaction comes from one address?

Answer (score 4):

Transactions can 'claim' from multiple addresses. In fact, the default client will do it if your balance is spread out amongst multiple addresses when you want to make a transaction.

Comment: Ah ok, so it's the wallet software choosing where. Got you.